# How to close an App from a Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have used the concept of `Fragments` in my Android App. I want to close my App from a fragment Activity. It's easy to do it in normal Activities by using onBackPressed() function, but how to do it in Fragments?

Comment: `getActivity().finish()`

Comment: but where should I put this?

Comment: I want to do this by pressing back button of the device.. not by using any button on fragment activity!

Comment: I don't see the point of doing this, this is already a natural behavior in Android.

Comment: if you want close the app on press back button then put following line of code in containing Activity
 @Override 
        public void onBackPressed() { 
        super.onBackPressed();
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

  }

Comment: @Enzokie There can also be some other activity used before opening the fragment. So if I press back button, it goes to that activity which I don't want!! I want to close it from the fragment. There is a Login activity before the Fragment is opened... So its going to the Login Activity again! I want to close the app from the Fragment Activity!

Answer (score 0):

Fragment never runs independent. Activity contain the fragment so if you want to go back just press back  button.

If you have any button in fragment to do so then write  `getActivity().finish();`inside button click method.

**EDIT 1** if you want to push your app in background then write following code

```
getActivity().moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The user can quit your app by pressing the Home button or navigate using the Back Button. Having a button in your app which closes it goes against best practices suggested by Google.